# Origin and meaning of "every cloud has a silver lining"

Tags: meaning

> Every cloud has a silver lining.

Please provide some historical perspective and meaning of this expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to *The Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs*, the phrase "Every cloud has a silver lining" is

> a poetic sentiment that even the gloomiest outlook contains some hopeful or consoling aspect. *Cf. [1634 Milton Comus I. 93] Was I deceiv'd, or did a sable cloud Turn forth her silver lining on the night?*

Read more: http://www.answers.com/topic/silver-lining#ixzz1Cu5fvfWP and http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=silver+lining&searchmode=none

Both cite John Milton's *Comus 1* as the first instance of this expression.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of clouds having silver linings comes from the fact that when the sun (or moon) bursts through a cloud it looks as if the interior is silver.

The sun bursting through a cloud is a good metaphor for a problem eventually having a positive outcome.